# is it possible to do something like that with a regular expression? if not, what are the alternatives?

Tags: regex, formatting

Suppose I have a text file with some data I want to retrieve lost in a sea of regular written language.
Each piece of data I want to retrieve is a tuple of 3 numbers between 0 and 99  (that I will call N1 to N3), which can be formatted in 4 different ways:

- `N1-N2-N3`
- `N1N2N3`
- `N1.N2.N3`
- `N1/N2/N3`

Using regular expressions, is it possible to describe something like that:
*Something I will call `separator` later is something in this list :* `[ '-', '', '.', '/' ]`
*My expression is like:* `N1{separator}N2{same_separator_as_the_first_one}N3`
?

It seems like the only way to express that is:
*My expression is like:* `({N1}-{N2}-{N3}) OR ({N1}{N2}{N3}) OR ({N1}.{N2}.{N3}) OR ({N1}/{N2}/{N3})`

...which becomes quickly unreadable...

Is it possible to achieve the first kind of expression with regular expressions? Is there something available which is not regex that allows this kind of expressiveness?

The real question is:

> Given the available formats, what is the best way to write a function
>   which gets a string and returns N1 to N3 along with the used separator
>   character (and throws an exception when the string does not match any
>   format)?

Comment: We can help with the regex, but we can't help with "the best way to write a function" unless you tell us what language it's supposed to be in!

Comment: This is almost certainly possible, but it would be helpful if you let us know which regular expression engine you are using.

Comment: I was just looking for the `{same_separator_as_the_first_one}` thing, the regex engine does not matter (neither does the language once I think about it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends slightly on the flavor of regex, but in a typical language, I would write:

```
([1-9]?[0-9])([-./]?)([1-9]?[0-9])\2([1-9]?[0-9])
```

Then group 2 is the separator, and groups 1, 3, and 4 are the three numbers.

Comment: great! the \2 thing was the one I missed for all those years!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should look like:

```
N1([-\./])N2\1N3
```

Where the `\1` indicates "whatever was matched inside of the first parenthesis", e.g., whatever was matched by `[-\./]`. Of course, in the non-separator case, you'd need to know more about the form of N1 and N2 to guarantee a match. If "is an integer" is all you have, you may have a hard time (when does N1 end and N2 begin?).

What you're looking for, in general are so-called 'back-references'. See here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html.

Answer (score 0):

In the formal definition of a regular expression, you can't have a "same-separator-as-the-last-one" without enumerating them, as you did  in your "quickly unreadable" solution.  You need a context-free grammar to "remember" something like that; fortunately (as others have pointed out) most regex implementations include such capabilities.

Comment: so the problem i am trying to solve cannot be solved easily in the formal definition but most implementations will provide a way to express what I want in a non-standard way?

Comment: I think its a pretty standard feature, and provided in a pretty standard way.  Its just that the name "regular expression" has a formal meaning which doesn't include it, but because of their usefulness, most "regular expression" packages include them.

Comment: @fonzo: One could say that the term "regular expression" has two separate meanings: as a formal computer science term, it refers to a type of notation for expressing a "regular language", and as a programming term, it refers to a type of object or entity that was inspired by, but is not coextensive with, the computer-science concept. The computer-science usage is the original use, and when it's important to distinguish the two concepts, the programming term is usually demoted to "pattern" or "regex".

Comment: tell me more scott. I thought regular expressions were something almost generic and standardized (does this word even exist in english?).... forget it then, i did not think the implementation was so important. could you please explain what is the best implementation and why the way it allows itself to get out of the standard way is so good? i lack a lot in this field...... (unfortunately :(

Comment: @ruakh: ok. you've just explained in less than an hour all that i was looking for in regex for something like the last 10 years. i'd appreciate if you could put the important words in bold for further readings, but anyway you are the best. tank you regex-sensei!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this using [Python's Regular Expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) library:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> text = '''12-34-56
... 654321
... 24.68.10
... 1/86/42
... Nonsense
... 00-000-0000-00000
... '''
>>>
>>> for line in text.split('\n'):
...     m = re.match(r'^(\d{1,2})([-/.]?)(\d{1,2})\2(\d{1,2})$', line)
...     if m:
...         print m.group(1), m.group(3), m.group(4), 'were separated by [', m.group(2), ']'
...     else:
...         print '[', line, ']', 'was badly-formed'
...
12 34 56 were separated by [ - ]
65 43 21 were separated by [  ]
24 68 10 were separated by [ . ]
1 86 42 were separated by [ / ]
[ Nonsense ] was badly-formed
[ 00-000-0000-00000 ] was badly-formed
[  ] was badly-formed
```

Comment: ok, so back referencing the separator was the key? did you put a '-' between "badly" and "formed" to scrape back your test results or is it just some kind of python constraint?

Comment: If you say so. I put the hyphen there because it looked right to me.